# Need the dozen or more titles part

Tags: sql, oracle

Full question
For only those films that were produced after 1990, show the number of each of the different genre of film, as well as the cheapest, most expensive and average cost of film for each category.  Only display those genre that include a dozen or more titles.

```
SELECT GENRE_CODE          AS "Genre",
       COUNT(TITLE)        AS "How many titles in this genre",
       MIN(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS "Cheapest",
       MAX(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS "Most Expensive",
       AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS "Average",
       PRODUCTION_YEAR
FROM   MOVIE
WHERE  PRODUCTION_YEAR > 1990
GROUP  BY GENRE_CODE,
          PRODUCTION_YEAR
```

I have this part I don't understand the dozen or more titles part.

How would I single out the genre that has multiple titles

Comment: A `dozen` = 12, the same way donuts (or wines, 12 bottles a case) are typically sold, so 12+ for the `dozen or more`.

Comment: A dozen or more means 12 or more, and you're looking for the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT GENRE_CODE          AS "Genre",
       COUNT(*)            AS "How many titles in this genre",
       MIN(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS "Cheapest",
       MAX(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS "Most Expensive",
       AVG(PURCHASE_PRICE) AS "Average",
       PRODUCTION_YEAR
FROM   MOVIE
WHERE  PRODUCTION_YEAR > 1990
GROUP  BY GENRE_CODE,
          PRODUCTION_YEAR
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 12
```

*(You can also use `COUNT(*)` as this will count the rows in the group rather than `COUNT(title)` which would need to read the `title` value and check it is not `NULL` and would only count those non-`NULL` rows, so may not include films that are in your database that do not have a title yet.)*